# callback needs access to multiple topics - how?

Tags: ros, kinect, cv-bridge, image-transport, image-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do some processing on images published by a kinect but this is a general camera-related question.

I would like to use the image_geometry functions contained in the PinholeCameraModel for converting 3d rays to pixels and 2d pixels to 3d rays, while making use of the calibration parameters published under /camera/rgb/camera_info.

The [documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/image_geometry/html/c++/) gives an example like this:

```
image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel model_;

void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& raw_image,
             const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& cam_info)
{
  // Update the camera model (usually a no-op)
  model_.fromCameraInfo(cam_info);

  // Do processing...
}
```

Defining a subscriber like this doesn't work though:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/rgb/image_rect /camera/rgb/camera_info", 1, &imageCb);
```

I'm guessing that I have to do something to group the image with the camera_info into one single message, perhaps with image_transport(?), but I don't have any idea how to do this.
I suppose i could create a separate callback for the camera info and update some global variable that the other callback could access but I think that's a less than ideal solution in general (in this case I'm sure it works, since the calibration parameters are constant).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11774/callback-needs-access-to-multiple-topics---how?/) by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 465 on 2011-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I think I might have found an answer so:

The problem lies in the use of the ros::Subscriber.

To get both the image and the camera_info simultaneously (and synchronized), use image_transport CameraSubscriber instead.

```
image_transport::CameraSubscriber sub = it.subscribeCamera("camera/rgb/image", 1, &imageCb);
```

The callback function can be left as-is.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) with karma: 465 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5